# Custom MVC template for enum to drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap

I have created several MVC templates for the EditorFor and DisplayFor helper methods to style things the way I wanted using the Twitter Bootstrap framework.  I now have a working solution for all the bits I need, but would like to generalize one part I set up to show a list of states.  I have a State enum (with a list of all US states) that I display in a drop down for a users address.  I used the [DataType] attribute to get MVC to use my State.cshtml template.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "State")]
[DataType("State")]
public State State { get; set; }
```

So it works nicely, but I would like to change it so that I can do something like DataType("Enum") or some other way to hit this template generically for all enums.

The template looks like this:

```
@using System
@using System.Linq
@using Beno.Web.Helpers
@using TC.Util

@model Beno.Model.Enums.State

<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m, new {@class = "control-label{0}".ApplyFormat(ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired ? " required" : "")})
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m)
            <span class="add-on">@(new MvcHtmlString("{0}".ApplyFormat(ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired ? " <i class=\"icon-star\"></i>" : "")))</span>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m, null, new {@class = "help-inline"})
    </div>
</div>
```

The EnumDropDownListFor is a helper method I posted about before and that works generically with any enum.  What I don't know is how would I change this template to take a generic enum as the model object?

**UPDATE:** For completeness I include a listing of the EnumDropDownListFor method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null) where TProperty : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(TProperty).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("TProperty must be an enumerated type");

    var selectedValue = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).Model.ToString();
    var selectList = new SelectList(from value in EnumHelper.GetValues<TProperty>()
                                    select new SelectListItem
                                                {
                                                    Text = value.ToDescriptionString(),
                                                    Value = value.ToString()
                                                }, "Value", "Text", selectedValue);

    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Changing the model type to Enum produces the following error on the line with the call to the helper method:

```
CS0453: The type 'System.Enum' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'TProperty' in the generic type or method 'Beno.Web.Helpers.ControlHelper.EnumDropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, object)'
```

Then if I remove the check if TProperty is an enum and the struct where constraint, I get a compile error on the line where I am trying to get the enum values of:

```
System.ArgumentException: Type 'Enum' is not an enum
```

I wonder if it's just not possible to do what I am trying here.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Enum

Answer (score 1):

You could just create an EditorTemplate `Enum.cshtml`

All you would have to do is change this line :

```
@model Beno.Model.Enums.State
```

For this :

```
@model System.Enum
```

You will then be able to use any `Enum` with it.

The catch: the engine can't infer the base class of an item thus, TestEnum won't be assigned the Enum template, so you would have to call it explicitly :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnumValue, "Enum")
```

Comment: I tried that already, but had issues with the line @Html.EnumDropDownListFor.  With the model being of type Enum, it could not figure out the type of the enum.  I will update the question with the signature of the helper method to be more clear.

Comment: I would see the problem originating from `EnumHelper.GetValues<TProperty>()` if there is a check in there on the type of TProperty you would get the `Type 'Enum' is not an enum` error. You could check in that helper how you could change your call to make it work.

Comment: Yea.  I feel it can be done somehow, I just don't know how.  Will update this again if I ever solve the problem.  As always in life, I have a working solution for States, so have to get the project to a point where I can deploy, then I can cycle back and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand exactly what you mean, but try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EnumName, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Namespace.Models.EnumName))))
```

EnumName = State in your case.

I've used the above to get an enum into a drop down list using Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Well, I use my generic helper method to create the drop down list for any enum.  The problem is related to trying to do that from a MVC template with a generic enum as type instead of my specific State enum.  I can easily call the helper method directly from the view and at that point it knows what type it is, but once you make the extra code jump to the template, it no longer works.  I do have the actual type in the ModelMetadata though.  Wonder if I could cast it somehow before passing it to the helper?

Comment: Dynamically casting it could be an option - but one I'm afraid I won't be able to help you with! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I too have been trying to achieve this.

Is the idea that you want to be able to use one template for all Enum types in all your models.
This way you have an Enum Template in the EditorTemplates folder that allow you to display them as drop down lists.

I have been following this article. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/05/21/asp-net-mvc-creating-a-dropdownlist-helper-for-enums.aspx

The issue you have is that your template passes the type of System.Enum in the TModel and TProperty

```
Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
```

Then when you perform the following below TProperty is of Type System.Enum not Beno.Model.Enums.State

```
 EnumHelper.GetValues<TProperty>()
```

To get around this I do not bother looking at TProperty as it does not give me the right type.

Instead I look at the metadata.ModelType.

```
ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
```

This gives me the correct type but you can't use these in within the Covariance Derived class

```
EnumHelper.GetValue<metadata.ModelType> //This does not work.
```

So I rewrote the body to not use any generics.

```
        public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression)
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        var values = Enum.GetValues(metadata.ModelType);

        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var v in values)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = Regex.Replace(v.ToString(), "([A-Z][a-z])", " $1").Trim(),
                Value = v.ToString(),
                Selected = v.Equals(metadata.Model)
            });
        }

        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items);

    }
```

You may need to change the method signature to include your htmlattributes.

Answer (score 0):

As others show, writing a custom helper is the way to go. This is exactly what was done in [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/). Among other helpers it has a helper `DropDownListFromEnumFor(...)`, which you'd use like so:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().DropDownListFromEnumFor(m => m.SomeEnum)
```

or

```
@Html.Bootstrap().DropDownListFromEnum("SomeEnum")
```

The cool thing about BMVC is that you can customize the dropdown with extension methods some of which are for regular html and others are Bootstrap specific. Below are some of them:

```
@(f.ControlGroup().DropDownListFromEnumFor(m => m.SomeEnum)
    .Append("something")
    .AppendIcon("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right")
    .Class("cool-dd")
    .OptionLabel("-- Select --")
    .Tooltip("cool tooltip"))
```

Oh, and yeah, the example above will generate full control-group - input, label, and validation message.

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author of TwitterBootstrapMVC

Comment: what about a nullable enum?